# sql - take values from one column to another (seperate databases)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases: `database1` and `database2`. Both databases have a table called `users` and both users tables have a column called `username` and `avatar`

So, to break it down:

**database1:**

- `users`

  - `username`
  - `avatar`

**database2:**

- `users`

  - `username`
  - `avatar`

My question is: How can I select the values from `database1.users.avatar` and add the values from that column to `database2.users.avatar`, WHERE the usernames are a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
UPDATE database2.users, database1.users 
SET database2.users.avatar = database1.users.avatar 
WHERE database2.users.username = database1.users.username;
```

Comment: @oliverbj, check the updated answer. This should work. Earlier one was for sql server. Sorry for my haste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
 UPDATE database2.users u2
    INNER JOIN database1.users u1 
    ON u2.username= u2.username
 SET u2.avatar=u1.avatar;
```